# Implementation query of mongodb to php?

Tags: php, mongodb

All this time, I just used php mongodb look like:

**query**

```
db.collection.find()
db.collection.find({"name":"foo"})
```

**transformation in php**

```
db->collection->find()
db->collection->find(array("name"=>"foo"))
```

And the conclusion is

```
1. dot(.) has been changed to ->
2. brackets({}) has been changed to array()
3. colon(:) has been changed to =>
```

The question is how to tranform this code into php:

```
db.chat.find({ "_id":"2" })
  .forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.chat.forEach(function (ch) {
      if (ch.sender === "foo") {
        ch.status="sent";
      }
    });
    db.chat.save(doc);
  });
```

When I tried

**query**

```
db.collection.find().forEach(printjson)
```

**transformation into php**

```
db->collection->find()->forEach(printjson)
```

That code couldn't work, and there's something wrong with message

**Fatal error:** Call to undefined method MongoCursor::forEach()

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)** construct on the **[`find()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php)** cursor as well as the `chat` array of each doc in the loop to do the update. The following example shows this approach:

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('test');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'chats');

// search for _id
$query = array('_id' => '2');

$cursor = $collection->find($query);
foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
    var_dump($doc); // log the doc in iteration
    foreach ($ch as $doc->chat) {
        var_dump($ch); // log the chat item before update
        if ($ch->sender === '') {
            $ch->status = 'sent';
        }
        var_dump($ch); // log the chat item after update
    }
    $collection->save($doc);
}

?>
```

Comment: Nothing error but it couldn't update. The status didn't change. I changed the code like this $ch->sender === 'foo', still couldn't change. And I changed the code still $ch->sender === '', also couldn't change.

Comment: Are you sure you are updating the correct database and collection instances? Mind you, the above references an example db and collection and you need to make sure there is actual data in the collection. Perhaps put some `var_dump($doc);` statements in your code to show the actual data being iterated.

Comment: When I put var_dump($doc) into the code. It still couldn't work sir. Omg what can I do ? :( The database and collection instances are correct. Just your code selected collection chats but I already changed to chat but it still couldn't work...

Comment: And var_dump($doc), I think there's something wrong. My page is blank.

Comment: Check if there's data in the collection, query in mongo shell first e.g. `db.chat.find({_id: '2'})`, if that doesn't return a document then it didn't find a match.

Comment: Sir, it shows var_dump($doc); // log the doc in iteration but stops before foreach ($ch as $doc->chat) . Am I right ?

Comment: What is displayed when you push an additional statement `var_dump($doc->chat);` before the inner `foreach`?

Comment: array(3) { ["_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["osc"]=> string(5) "fauzy" ["chat"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(3) { ["sender"]=> string(5) "fauzy" ["message"]=> string(1) "a" ["status"]=> string(4) "pending" } [1]=> array(3) { ["sender"]=> string(5) "fauzy" ["message"]=> string(1) "b" ["status"]=> string(4) "pending" } [2]=> array(3) { ["sender"]=> string(5) "fauzy" ["message"]=> string(1) "c" ["status"]=> string(4) "pending" } } }

Comment: Any ideas sir ? I'm stucking. I don't know what can I do. Perhaps you'll answer my question. I'll wait until the answer has been done. :)